# Lasso Regression - getting LinAlgError: Singular matrix error

Tags: python, regression, p-value, lasso-regression

I have been trying to fit a Lasso Regression model to identify important characteristics (char) and value combination from my dataset. I have different titles with different characteristics, which further take different values.

My DataFrame looks like this:
[image: df]

I created a new column (char_value) with a combination of characteristics and values and then turned them into dummies to run regression (i.e. each char_value is now a new column with binary values). I used Lasso Regression, and got the R^2 (=.25), but while trying to get the p-values of the coefficient, I ran into LinAlgError. I tried looking for solutions for this but none of them solved the error. (My code is far from perfect so please excuse my lack of ability but any help to solve this problem would be appreciated.)

```
df = pd.crosstab([df["title"], df["quantity"]], df["char_value"])\
    .gt(0)\
    .astype(int)\
    .reset_index()


reg = LinearRegression()

y = df['quantity'].values
X = df.drop(['quantity', 'title'], axis=1).astype('float64')

y_reshaped = y.reshape(-1,1)

reg.fit(X, y)

list_numerical = X.columns
list_numerical

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.05, random_state=10)

scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train[list_numerical]) 

X_train[list_numerical] = scaler.transform(X_train[list_numerical])

X_test[list_numerical] = scaler.transform(X_test[list_numerical])

# Lasso with 5 fold cross-validation
model = LassoCV(cv=5, random_state=0, max_iter=10000)

# Fit model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

lasso_best = Lasso(alpha=model.alpha_)
lasso_best.fit(X_train, y_train)

list_of_combs = list(zip(lasso_best.coef_, X_train))
#     sorted(list_of_combs) 

print('R squared training set:', round(lasso_best.score(X_train, y_train)*100, 2))

stats.summary(lasso_best, X_train, y_train)
```

The error looked like this:
[image: Error message]